# Creating a readfile function with PPMImage

Tags: python, readfile

Super new at Python let alone coding. I am stuck on this assignment dealing with PPMImage and creating a readfile function.

Our professor gave us these hints for the function:

> "Create a PPMImage using the constructor and these three integers
>   above as arguments (store in a variable called image_variable). Loop
>   until end of file  Read red, green and blue components of pixel,
>   Append these to the list self.__pixels via method addpixel(), Close
>   filename Return the image_variable to caller"

What I have so far is this

```
def readfile(filename):
    fv = open(filename, "r")            ### Open filename for reading.
    line = fv.readline()                ### Read line containing "P3"
    line = fv.readline().rstrip().split() ###Read line containing integers width and height (hint: use rstrip() and split())
    line = fv.readline()   

    close = fv.close()
    return image_variable
```

Any tips on how to get the rest of the code that is needed? 
Thank you!

Comment: You should look up tutorials on how to make class and constructors (init()) since you did not make a constructor.

Comment: Try to implement all the things your professor instructed and then show us the code if your get any error.

Comment: first create Class and constructor `__init__(self)`. Now you have only function and you assign everything to the same variable `line` so you loose access to this inforamtion. you don't have to assign `close()` to variable.

Comment: BTW: if you ask for PPMImage then you should add some PPMImage example in question so everybody could test code on this example.